# How can I add an attribute to a mocked function and point it to None?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

My code:

```
def my_function: 
     uploaded_pass1_file = _pcontrol.storage(
                    session, pd.parsed_s3wrapper)



@mock.patch(<path_to_pcontrol>)
def my_unit_test(mock_pcontrol): 
    #Need to set _pcontrol so that it has a 'storage' attribute
```

In the above I mock out a function called `_pcontrol`, which in my function has an attribute called `storage`.

But I am not sure how to add an attribute `storage` to the mocked function `_pcontrol`.

I have tried doing something like `mock_pcontrol.storage = None` .

But when I set a breakpoint just above `uploaded_pass1_file` and `print(_pcontrol.stage)` it just says that its a MagicMock object, rather than pointing to `None`, which is what I desire.

Comment: Try to use `mock_pcontrol.storage.side_effect = None`. For an answer more details add code which could be executed please. Where is defined `_pcontrol` in your code? `session`? `pd`?